# How to setup Material Search bar in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview, material-components-android

I'm trying to implement a Material SearchBar in my Android app.
This should actually have a button on the left, which extends the left navigation layout (the code for the NavLayout is already available and functional) and a search field to filter something with an onTextChange listener.

I am thinking of a design similar to Gmail or the Material page example
(particularly with the Button location)

[image]

On The Material3 Website you can see that it is possible to have a design with a Button on the left, which could be used to open a NavigationDrawer and a Button on the right to open a Account Page or something similar

(link: https://m3.material.io/components/search/specs#0eca344e-55ba-4a57-9c15-18eb1591ea53)
->Here its called (1) Search Bar configuration with Avatar

But how can I apply such a theme with this functionality?

My Code:

search_menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/mail"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

activity_main.xml:
Within a constraint Layout

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
                android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:forceDefaultNavigationOnClickListener="false"
                android:hint="hallo" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt:

```
lateinit var searchBar: SearchBar
lateinit var searchView: SearchBar

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        searchBar = findViewById(R.id.search_bar)
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView)
        searchBar.inflateMenu(R.menu.search_menu)
        searchView.setupWithSearchBar(searchBar)
        searchBar.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item ->
            if(item.itemId == R.id.action_search){
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
            }
            true
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain detail about what you want, I really don't find it ?
You just want listen click on navigation left then open DrawerLayout ? Is that right ?

Comment: @NguyễnMinhKhoa yes exactly, i want to design the searchBar like you can see it in the examples in the given sources and pictures. so that it has a button on the left that opens the navigationDrawer and one on the right that opens an account activity. but unfortunately i can't get it to have this design as it is shown on many MaterialUi pages.

Thanks for pointing out the clarity of the question, I have revised it a bit and added more visuals about my target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set up like example in the document about SearchBar and Navigation Drawer
( Material Design 3 )

Structure of **.xml** should be

```
<DrawerLayout>
   <CoordinatorLayout>
       <AppBarLayout> 
           <SearchBar/>
       </AppBarLayout> 
           <SearchView>
           </SearchView>
   </CoordinatorLayout>
      <NavigationView/>
</DrawerLayout>
```

About the code **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
                android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                style="@style/Widget.Material3.SearchBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="hallo"
    // IMPORTANT CODE // app:forceDefaultNavigationOnClickListener="false"
    // IMPORTANT CODE // app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.search.SearchView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Search something"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/search_bar">

        </com.google.android.material.search.SearchView>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_navigation_drawer"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In **MainActivity** set up like this

```
val drawerLayout = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawerLayout)
val searchBar = findViewById<SearchBar>(R.id.search_bar)
searchBar.setNavigationOnClickListener { drawerLayout.open() }  // IMPORTANT CODE //

// To listen click on item menu on the right of SearchBar you need to set up like this
searchBar.inflateMenu(R.menu.<Your menu search bar>)
searchBar.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.test1-> {}
            R.id.test2-> {}
        }
        true
    }
```

**Video Result**

[image]

Comment if you get problem with this

Comment: It works, thank you a lot. But one question, do you know how I can change the color of the button on the right? (the one that comes with the menu.xml) I have tried it with `android:iconTint` but the drawable stays black.

Comment: Go to drawable find the one you want to change 
Look at -> android:tint=" "  <- 
@color/<WhatEverYouWant>
or 
?attr/<Change -> colorOnSurfaceVariant <- In__theme.xml__File>